# writing in textbox from anoter class (on another thread)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, class

I need to make classes in my program to start a chain of events to write a text in a textbox.
I know that the classes shouldn't know about the form. how to do that? take into account the fact that i'll instalize the class on another thread.

I've already tried making an interface which connects the classes and make method on the form with ref parameters.

**update:**you all misunderstood me- i was talking about events not in proggraming. all i need is add text to textbox from another class. i added the "chain of events" to define it from simila questions, in them they've tried to change the text drectly from the class. sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing enough about your application I'll suggest that what you need is to invoke an event in the class that is handled by the form. What happens is like this:

1. Class has an event.
2. Form starts up and instantiates class.
3. Form assigns a handler to the event in the class.
4. Class does whatever it needs to do, until it reaches the point where it needs to communicate with the form.
5. Class raises the event.
6. The handler in the form gets executed and the textbox changes.

So in the code of the class you'll need to add some definitions:

```
public delegate void FinishedEventHandler(object sender, string ValueToReturn);
public event FinishedEventHandler Finished;
```

The first is a delegate with the *signature* of the event. By convention the first argument is always a reference to the instance of the class itself, and the rest are the values you want to return. The second is the actual event.

Now, in the function that does whatever processing the class does we need to raise the event when appropriate:

```
void DoSomething()
{
    .
    .
    .
    if(Finished!=null) Finished(this, "some value");
}
```

The if clause is used to make sure that someone is actually handling our event, otherwise we might get an exception.

Now let's take a look at the form. We need to add a function that handles the event. It needs to have the same signature as the delegate we defined earlier. Within that function we do whatever changes we need to the form in light of the values we get back:

```
private void FinishedEventHandler(object sender, string ValueToReturn)
{
    TextBox1.Text = ValueToReturn;
}
```

Now we're ready to use all that plumbing we just created. First we add the handler to the event, then we can call the class's processing functions.

```
MyClass.Finished += FinishedEventHandler;
MyClass.DoSomething();
```

Here's a more detailed tutorial:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Actually all of that can be expressed in three lines of code, which can most certainly be done in the scope of a short answer.  Step 6 has no code associated with it, and steps 2 and 4 are things that realistically you can expect the OP to figure out on their own; they need not be in your answer.  This is indeed a good approach to use though.

Comment: One thing that System does not mention is is you are doing cross thread communication you will need to do a `Invoke` from inside the event handler in the form.

Comment: 1) When defining an event there's no need to define your own delegate type.  Just use `Action`/`Func`, or if you really feel obligated to use an event based handler you could use `EventHandler<string>`.  2) for assigning the event handler you can use a lambda, which is much more effective for these real small events, although a named method can always be used for non-trivial handlers.

Comment: For your update if you are in a multi-threaded enviorment the way you wrote your event raiser a `NullRefrenceException` can be raised if the last person unsubscribes from your event on a second thread in between the null check and the raising. The correct way is to use a temporary variable to store the event delegate. See [this post from Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx) for more information.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Shouldn't be relevant in this context.  The events shouldn't ever be added or removed while the method is running (in fact, there's no need for them to be removed at all; the form will outlive this object in all likelihood).

Comment: @Servy That is true, however IMHO the overhead of using a temp variable is small enough that that it should be used in all situations. If code gets re-used or re-factored and now the event is being called from a situation where it could be unsubscribed you have already protected yourself. Plus user1461837 appears to be new to C# and I think its good to let new people know about potential pitfalls that they could come across even if they won't face it right now, in case they change their mind on the design and the previous non-relevant gotcha is now relevant.

Comment: you all misunderstood me- i was talking about events not in proggraming. all i need is add text to textbox from another class. i added the "chain of events" to define it from simila questions, in them they've tried to change the text drectly from the class. sorry.

Comment: @user1461837 Nobody misunderstood you.  That other class should know nothing about the form, even through an interface.  Using events, in the programming sense, is the appropriate way of solving this problem.  Passing a reference to the form in some manor and directly accessing the UI from a processing class such as this is very poor practice, and just isn't nearly as maintainable.

Answer (score 4):

There are two likely options here:

The "other class" needs to update the textbox as soon as it's "done" with it's work.  If this is the case it should't ever know about the form, any textbox, an interface, nothing.  It should just *return a value* and let the form use that return value to set a textbox, or do whatever.

In most situations this is what you want to do, and it's both the easiest and most effective means of solving this type of problem.  Don't use something more complex if you don't have to.

If the information doesn't happen when the task is "done", but instead through periodic intervals then you can use the `Progress` class with the `IProgress` interface.

Have the `Form` create an instance: `Progress<string> progress = new Progress<string>();`.  have the form attach an event handler for that instance.  Note that the `Progress` instance will "capture" the current sync context, which is a fancy way of saying it runs in the UI thread.  This can be done like so:

```
progress.ProgressChanged += (_, data) => textBox1.Text = data;
```

Then just have the other class accept an `IProgress<string>` instance and periodically call:

```
progress.Report(someString);
```

If you need a pre-4.5 implementation of `Progress` and `IProgress`, here is an implementation that will compile and run in .NET 3.5+:

```
public interface IProgress<T>
{
    void Report(T data);
}

public class Progress<T> : IProgress<T>
{
    SynchronizationContext context;
    public Progress()
    {
        context = SynchronizationContext.Current
            ?? new SynchronizationContext();
    }

    public Progress(Action<T> action)
        : this()
    {
        ProgressReported += action;
    }

    public event Action<T> ProgressReported;

    void IProgress<T>.Report(T data)
    {
        var action = ProgressReported;
        if (action != null)
        {
            context.Post(arg => action((T)arg), data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that [IProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298.aspx) is new to .NET 4.5 so if you are targeting a earlier framework it will not be available.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain True, although it requires none of the newer language features; you can write your own `Progress` class/interface in just a few dozen lines of code.

Comment: Very true, I just did not want the OP to get caught off gard if he could not find the interface.

Comment: @user1461837 2010 isn't a version of .NET, it's a version of visual studio.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I added an implementation of Progress that compiles to 3.5 because I was bored.

Comment: Why do you check `context != null`. I have never worked with them before so I do not know, but to me from how it is written context will always have a value (unless `SynchronizationContext.Current` returns null, can that happen?)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain `SynchronizationContext.Current` can be null.  A good example is if you're in a Console application; there is no sync context.  Also, if you are already in a non-UI thread in a UI application (meaning the `Progress` object was created by a background thread) it's possible that there is no current sync context.

Comment: @Servy Thanks! I did not know and that likely would have bitten me if I tried using it, do you have any reccomended links on where I could learn how to use it correctly? The MSDN page for it is pretty sparse.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Oh, and then of course someone can always just write: `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);`.  It's pretty important when dealing with `await` to know if and when it's capturing a sync context, which is why I ended up looking into this.  If you end up looking into other such info it often talks about it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx) is a useful link.  It's not entirely on topic, but it's a cool blog post and it goes off on tangents that are relevant to this discussion.  See the other two parts of that series as well.